# What is dquilt and how do I get it?

Tags: software-installation, packaging

I have been doing some packaging lately, including patching. I read [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html) that I should do:

```
$ dpkg-source -x gentoo_0.9.12.dsc
$ cd gentoo-0.9.12
$ dquilt import ../foo.patch
$ dquilt push
$ dquilt refresh
$ dquilt header -e
... describe patch
```

But when I run anything with `dquilt`, I just get this error:

```
 Command 'quilt' from package 'quilt' (main)
 Command 'gquilt' from package 'gquilt' (universe)
 dquilt: command not found
```

So I did a check on it, and I still can't find it even with:

```
apt-cache show dquilt
```

Which outputted:

```
N: Unable to locate package dquilt
E: No packages found
```

So what is `dquilt`? Do I need it? Or will `quilt` do? And if I do need it, how do I get it?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Comment: Where did you get that `dquilt` command. It is `quilt`.

Comment: @Pilot6: I provide the link in my question.

Comment: quilt should be OK. I use it.

Comment: @Pilot6: So what is `dquilt`, and why is it in the official packaging documentation: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html ?

Comment: It says in section 3.1 "It's useful to have a slightly customized default, so let's create an alias dquilt for Debian packaging by adding the following lines to ~/.bashrc", `dquilt` is a customized default `quilt` command, not a package unto itself, I think

Comment: @markkirby: Oh, could you convert that into an answer please so that I can accept it. :)

Comment: Sure, I was not 100% sure, glad it cleared it up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says in section 3.1:

> It's useful to have a slightly customized default, so let's create an
>   alias dquilt for Debian packaging by adding the following lines to
>   ~/.bashrc

`dquilt` is a customized quilt command, not a package unto itself.

In short when `dquilt` is run it runs `quilt` with a set of customized parameters defined in `~/.bashrc`.